# Resizing NSTextView with NSAttributedString by decreasing font size by 50%, but frame of TextView decreases less than 50%

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview

I am adding a feature that allows the user to resize a view, that includes an `NSTextView` within it.

The `NSTextView` contains an `NSAttributedString`.

So for example if I wanted to resize the view by 50%:

- I would first decrease the frame of the container view by 50%
- Then I decrease the frame of the `NSTextView` by 50%
- Then I decrease the font size by 50% on `NSFont`, and apply it to my `NSAttributedString`

[image]
[image]

However, as you can see, the frame that the `NSAttributedString` takes up does not get reduced perfectly by 50%.  You can tell because there are characters on each line that overflow to the next line

At first I thought that maybe I was missing an attribute on the `NSAttributedString` that I also needed to reduce by 50%, so I logged out all of the attributes:

```
2015-11-12 15:54:13.959 Snagit[48707:8030724] BEFORE RESIZE {
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Helvetica 70.00 pt. P [] (0x610000056530) fobj=0x6000001f7300, spc=19.45\"";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 2, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0.05, HeaderLevel 0";
}
2015-11-12 15:54:13.960 Snagit[48707:8030724] ADDING FONT {
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Helvetica 35.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247a10) fobj=0x6000001f6900, spc=9.74\"";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 2, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0.05, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

As you can see, the attributes that appear to matter, is the `NSFont` attribute.  And both the Font Size, and the "`spc`" seem to be perfectly halved.

Yet the view still isn't perfectly half the size.

I could add a "magic number" and make the new size slightly smaller than 50%, but I feel like that just masks an underlying problem, and may have issues if the user resizes larger, like 200%

It's entirely possible that I'm missing something very obvious, but I'm just pretty stumped right now.  What could be the problem?  My closest guess is that there is a text attribute that I'm missing (kerning or something) that needs to be reduced by 50% as well.  But I just can't see anything

Comment: your font reduced twice, but text container margins remain the same

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete answer, but my take on it would be: fonts are complicated things.  They contain things like kerning adjustments between letter pairs that can vary depending on the point size of the text.  There may also be other spacings added in that you are not accounting for; what about the text container margin, for example?  But even if you account for all of the spacings that are accessible to you through APIs, you may still not get there because of the font metrics and their potential dependency on point size.  Maybe a different approach that would work better would be to actually change the coordinate system of the view that encloses the `NSTextView`, using `scaleUnitSquareToSize:`; that might adjust things more reliably.